# Selectively remove Chrome (Android) browsing history

Tags: history

All I found is help on desktop based Chrome, like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597884/selectively-remove-chrome-browsing-history

Is there a way to select a part of the history but in Android?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome in Android, select the Menu in the top-right, and in that menu select History. In the history view you should see an X at the right side of each item in the list. Pressing this should remove that item from your browsong history.

Tested on
Samsung Galaxy S5
Android 6.0.1
Chrome 54.0.2840.85

Comment: The problem is that you can not delete every item at once, you have to delete them one by one, and after every delete, the History is realoaded, and you have to find once again in which part of the History you were

Answer (score 0):

There's an online which stores everything you surf.. You can go there and delete it..

[Google History](http://history.google.com)

And same way you can check or delete your stored passwords..

[Google Password](http://passwords.google.com)

Comment: Only if you have it enabled, in my case I don't.